# Como passar um JSON para o front end Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express.js

Olá! Eu queria saber se tem algum jeito de eu passar um arquivo JSON para o Front End, usando Express...

Estou usando esse método:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})
```

E, eu quero saber como se manda um .JSON para o front end... No caso, ele iria "receber" usando um JavaScript normal...

**Atenção**
Não quero usar nenhuma biblioteca ou frameWork. Apenas o Express.

Answer (score 0):

Para carregar o conteúdo do arquivo JSON no servidor de forma síncrona:

```
var fs = require('fs');
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json());
var jsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('meuArquivo.json', 'utf8'));
```

Depois para exibir na tela:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json(jsonData);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de resolver o problema é adicionando uma nova rota que vai fazer o envio do conteúdo do arquivo.

Segue um exemplo da declaração do controller:

```
app.get("/arquivo", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/saida.json')
}
```

Isso vai exibir o conteúdo do arquivo acessar a rota `/arquivo`.

---

É possível também enviar o arquivo como anexo (attachment), isso vai fazer o navegador fazer o download do arquivo como um anexo. O arquivo será baixado para um diretório padrão.

Para conseguir este efeito basta utilizar a função [`attachment`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.attachment)

Segue um exemplo de implementação:

```
const fs = require('fs');

app.get("/download", (req, res) => {
    const conteudo = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+ '/saida.json');
    res.attachment('saida.json')
    res.status(200).send(conteudo);
}
```

Agora ao acessar a rota `/download` o arquivo será exibido na forma de um anexo e seu conteúdo será feito o download para o diretório padrão onde são salvos os arquivos. O diretório que serão baixadas as imagens é uma configuração padrão do browser.